# SQL - How to find all users that sent/received at least 5 messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a query that indicates all users who sent/received at least 5 messages in total. The tables are the following:

MessengerID:

```
+------+--------------+
| user | MessengerID  |
+------+--------------+
|Julie |         5566 |
|Amber |         7777 |
| Caio |         8998 |
| Lisa |         9911 |
| Jack |         6543 |
+------+--------------+
```

messages:

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| n  | sender |recipient| messages|
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 12 |   5566 |   7777 |        5 |
|  9 |   9911 |   5566 |        1 |
| 13 |   6543 |   7777 |        4 |
|  4 |   6543 |   5566 |        8 |
|  8 |   7777 |   9911 |        2 |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
```

The 'messages' column indicates the number of messages sent/received in each messenger chat. The problem is that the messenger ID can be both in the sender column and recipient columns. Please, consider the aggregated number of sent/received messages in the calculations. I don't want to calculate only sent or received messages per user.

Do you know what I could do? I am solving it with MySQL.

Comment: What happen to your question? You still want it or not? You can rollback if you want

Comment: There, I've rollback it. Is it ok now?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Yes! Thank you very much.

Comment: Is message column in message table showing total messages send by sender ??

Comment: @AmitVerma The 'messages' column indicates the number of messages sent/received in each messenger chat between two users. Sorry, I will clarify this information in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like this should work:

```
select user, sum(duration)
from (
    select caller as user, sum(duration) as duration
    from phone_calls
    group by caller
    union all
    select call_r as user, sum(duration) as duration
    from phone_calls
    group by call_r
) as t
group by user
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have to write a query that indicates all users who sent at least 5 messages.

If you want users who *send* menders, then you only care about the sender.  That would be:

```
select sender
from t
group by sender
having count(*) >= 5;
```

Comment: Sorry. Actually, I want to select the users who sent/received at least 5 messages in total. I don't want to calculate only sent or received messages per user, but both of them per user.  I will correct it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

your query could be like this.

```
SELECT MID.[USER], T2.MSGCOUNT 
FROM MessengerID MID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SENDER, SUM(MSGCOUNT)MSGCOUNT FROM
    (
        SELECT SENDER, SUM(MESSAGES) MSGCOUNT
        FROM MESSAGES GROUP BY SENDER
        UNION
        SELECT RCEPIENT, SUM(MESSAGES) 
        FROM MESSAGES GROUP BY RCEPIENT
    ) X GROUP BY SENDER HAVING SUM(MSGCOUNT)>=5
) T2 ON MID.MessengerID = T2.SENDER
```

I have assumed that sum of send/received count should be greater than or equal to 5. If you want change in condition than let me know.